# How do I determine if two lists of numpy arrays are equal

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following arrays:

```
myarray1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
myarray2 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
```

I get an error if I do the following:

```
myarray1==myarray2

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My ultimate goal is to see if they are both exactly the same. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [21]: alist1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
    ...: alist2 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
In [22]: alist1==alist2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [22] in <cell line: 1>
    alist1==alist2
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Do a test like this:

```
In [26]: [np.array_equal(a,b) for a,b in zip(alist1, alist2)]
Out[26]: [True, True, True]
In [27]: all(_)
Out[27]: True
```

`list` equal checks for identical `id`, and failing that for `==`.  But `==` for arrays is elementwise, so doesn't produce a single value for each pair.  We have to work around that, getting a single True/False for each pair, and then combining those.

```
In [28]: [a==b for a,b in zip(alist1, alist2)]
Out[28]: 
[array([ True,  True,  True,  True]),
 array([ True,  True,  True]),
 array([ True,  True,  True])]
```

Comment: I don't think this quite works. e.g. `myarray1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]`
`myarray2 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6])]`

Comment: I tested it on your original lists which matched in length.  You may need to add a `len(myarray1(==len(myarray2)` test first.  `zip` stops with the shortest list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array_equal(array1, array2)` for this.

Alternatively, `all(array1 == array2)`

Comment: did you test that on the OP's example?

Answer (score 0):

use `.array_equal()`. But you need to be careful as you have a list of numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

myarray1 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]
myarray2 = [np.array([1,2,3,4]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([7,8,9])]


np.array_equal(myarray1[0], myarray2[0])

True
```

but

```
np.array_equal(myarray1, myarray2)

False
```

@hpailj has the solution though for you above. So accept that solution.

Comment: Why would the second example evaluate to false if all elements are the same?

Comment: Refer to @hpaulj's solution